# .NET doesn't support non-standard XMLDSIG signature element names

Tags: .net, standards-compliance, signedxml, xml-dsig

I'm trying to implement an industry spec that requires enveloped XML digital signatures (XMLDSIG).  Instead of conforming to the examples (`<Signature>`) my spec uses its own name for the signature element:

```
<xs:element name="ensembleSignature" type="dsig:SignatureType" />
<!-- wish this was:  <xs:element ref="dsig:Signature" />  -->
```

So the element isn't named 'Signature' and is in the domain's XML namespace instead of the dsig XML namespace.

With a lot of extra work I can create this custom signature in .NET.

1. Using the .NET SignedXml class I create <dsig:Signature> element
2. I manipulate the DOM to remove <dsig:Signature> and recreate the element as <myns:ensembleSignature>.

But it seems .NET can't verify the incoming <myns:ensembleSignature>, even if I rename the incoming element back to <dsig:Signature>.

I've been over the XMLDSIG spec many times, and although all their examples use <Signature> it doesn't seem to specifically require this element name, even for enveloped transforms.  So is this a bug in SignedXml that it only supports this single element name when there is no such requirement in XMLDSIG spec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a non-standard element name isn't possible in .NET.  But the signature element name isn't part of the digest, so you can remove the 'custom' signature element and add a 'standard' signature element name (<Signature>) but be careful not to change any whitespace or namespaces in the SignedInfo element, because SignedInfo *IS* part of the digest.  In the canonicalization method I am using whitespace is significant, and so is the namespace of the elements.

1. load XML into XmlDocument
2. find <customSignature xmlns="http://b-to-b.com/Namespace">
3. create new element <Signature>
4. move all children of <customSignature> to

   - Be careful not to disturb whitespace or namespace context of <SignedInfo>.
5. replace <customSignature> with <Signature>
6. verify signature using .NET SignedXml class