# Verifying SignedXml with dsig prefix

Tags: .net, xml, digital-signature, xml-dsig, signedxml

I'm trying to generate SignedXML with dsig prefix (which I have managed to do thanks to George Dima's answer in [xml signature DS prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219232/xml-signature-ds-prefix/14874749)).

The problem is that the CheckSignature method is now returning false - I am thinking that this method may also need to be overridden just like the ComputeSignature method was however I am lost on how to do that.

Does anyone have a complete answer on how to generate SignedXML with  prefix but that can also be verified with CheckSignature please?

I can assure you that I've gone through all related posts about this topic but I haven't come across any that provide a complete solution:

[.NET doesn't support non-standard XMLDSIG signature element names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371356/net-doesnt-support-non-standard-xmldsig-signature-element-names)

[Generating xml signature with "ds" prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756051/generating-xml-signature-with-ds-prefix)

[Generating XADES-BES with “ds” prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799894/generating-xades-bes-with-ds-prefix)

[Generating xml signature with "ds" prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756051/generating-xml-signature-with-ds-prefix)

[.NET Signed XML Prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381517/net-signed-xml-prefix)

Thanks!

Comment: Dis you change this line XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Signature") to XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("ds:Signature")?

Comment: Hi Louise, yes I did do that ... still same issue

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing: Add ds to sig and have seen George Dima's post and am going to try it later today. I'll let you know. I don't think you should have to change CheckSignature because what if it needs to be checked by an external party as it is in my case? This should work without having to change CheckSignature.

Comment: Have you managed to get anywhere with that solution @LouiseEggleton?

Comment: I managed to talk the vendor into changing their end, but I am still curious as to how to do this, so I will have a look this evening.